# Is it possible to map parameters to a path in Spring Rest?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I've a legacy system where query parameters are used to determine the class/method for a request using a simple in-house framework. E.g.

```
/endpoint?product=foo&action=bar&amount=1.0
/endpoint?product=foo&action=baz&amount=1.0
```

And I'd like map all actions for a product to one class so the plumbing can be greatly simplified, e.g.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/endpoint/foo/**")
public class FooController {

  @AutoWire
  private FooProductService s; // one of many beans that have to be wired into lots of classes

  @RequestMapping("/bar")
  public void bar(@PathVariable String amount, Model model) {    
    // implementation omitted
  }
  @RequestMapping("/baz")
  public void baz(@PathVariable String amount, Model model) {    
    // implementation omitted
  }
```

}

It's a published API so we can't change the public API -> the URLs cannot change.

I thought that perhaps this could be done using configuration, as aspect or even a custom framework with out own annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can do something like this for product=foo&action=bar&amount=1.0

```
@RequestMapping(value = "product={productName}&action={someaction}&amount={value}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
something(@PathVariable String productName, @PathVariable String someaction, @PathVariable String value)
    if(someaction.equals("bar")) {
        //do bar
    } 
    if(someaction.equals("baz")) {
        //do baz
    } 
}
```

HTH